# Description of assembly hello world

Tags: assembly

I am interested in learning assembly (x86) language and made my first hello-world program. I used the debugger in windows-xp and I wonder if someone could explain what every line does.

```
 1) jmp 115
 2) db 'Hello world!$'
 3) -a 115 
 4) mov ah, 09
 5) mov dx, 102
 6) int 21
 7) int 20
```

I have attached a screenshoot of the every step to make a executable file in assembly,

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend that you read [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (especially volume 2), and/or some x86 assembly tutorial (like [The Art of Assembly](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html).

Breakdown of the code:

```
1) jmp 115
```

Jumps to the `mov ah,09` instruction, so that the CPU doesn't try to execute the 'Hello world' string as if it was code (the CPU can't tell the difference between code and data).

---

```
2) db 'Hello world!$'
```

Declares a string. The dollar-sign is used as a string terminator by some DOS interrupt functions.

---

```
3) -a 115
```

Tells `debug` to assemble subsequent code starting at address 115.

---

```
4) mov ah, 09
```

Puts the value 9 in register `ah`.

---

```
5) mov dx, 102
```

Puts the address of the 'Hello world' string in register `dx`

---

```
6) int 21
```

Performs interrupt 21h / function 9 ([write string](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm)). The function number is expected in register `ah` and the string offset in register `dx`, which was taken care of by the previous two instructions.

---

```
7) int 20
```

Performs interrupt 20h ([terminate program](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2471.htm))

Comment: I would add that the values that go into `ah` and `dx` are prescribed by the documentation of services offered by the DOS operating system. You would have to look them up to use them. `int 21` and `int 20` are like function calls to those services.  See [Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm).